# What are the advantages of separate controller per partial view in mvc 4?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to MVC and just have learned about partial views.

What are the differences/advantages between separate controller per partial view vs only one controller per view (containing multiple partial views)?

Answer (score 1):

**Some definitions**

[`PartialView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.partialview%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) are pieces of code you use to add into a `View` or a result from an Action.

[`View`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.view%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) is a page you want to show to a user and it is returned by an Action from a Controller.

All `.cshtml` are consider by asp.net mvc as a View, depending on the way you treat the object, it becomes partially or not. (Html.RenderPartial, PartialView controller method, etc..).

**What you can do?**

- Sometimes you need to return just a piece and you can do it by a async request (using `ajax`). In these cases, you use an action that returns a Partial View.
- Sometimes you need to implement an View that need to add a piece of code, so, you can render it using a Partial View.
- You can have an View inside the `View/Shared` folder and this view could use an Partial View. The Partial View could be into the specific folder of the View. For sample:

  - Views

    - Product

      - Item.cshtml // Partial view
    - Shared

      - Index.cshtml // View

The content on the `Index.cshtml` file is:

```
<div>
 @Html.Partial("Item")
</div>
```

and you have an controller like this:

```
public class ProductController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

It will find an View in Product and not found, after will find in the Shared folder and render. The view in shared folder uses the Partial View, so, the context of the execution is in Product and it will render the `Item.cshtml` partial view from Product Folder.

If you do in your controller this:

```
public class ProductController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return PartialView();
    }
}
```

It will return just the process of `Index.cshtml` without any layout page, because you treat it as a Partial View.

Its some advantages you can use of Partial Views.